# evaluation of convergence of series with irrational terms

Tags: convergence-divergence

> Evaluation of convergence of series $$\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{5\sqrt{k}}{6k^2\sqrt{k}-2k+7}$$ using camparasion or limit Camparasion Test

What i try

$$\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{5\sqrt{k}}{6k^2\sqrt{k}-2k+7}\approx\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{5\sqrt{k}}{6k^2\sqrt{k}}=\frac{5}{7}\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{1}{k^2}.$$

Which is converge using $p$ series test.

So our original series is converges.

But i have a problem i have just approximate it.can anyone explain me  a fair way to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough to show that

$$\frac{5\sqrt{k}}{6k^2\sqrt{k}-2k+7}<\frac1{k^2}.$$

Comment: Thanks Yves daoust. I have a doubt on problem like $\displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{n}{n^2+2}$ which is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{n}$ (Diverges using p series test) but using Divergence test or integral test . It is Diverges.Please explain me.

Comment: @jacky: enter another question about this.

Comment: Ok Yves Daoust.